# ManagerInterface not found with SonataMediaBundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I tried to install `SonataMediaBundle` as described [here](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/installation.html).
After installation I'm getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Model\ManagerInterface' not found in /var/www/prj/vendor/sonata-project/media-bundle/Sonata/MediaBundle/Model/MediaManagerInterface.php on line 20
```

There is a `Sonata\CoreBundle\Entity\ManagerInterface` but no `Sonata\CoreBundle\Model\ManagerInterface`!
What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `CoreBundle` and `AdminBundle` were updated recently and this namespace changed. Until it's solved you can ensure that you are using the most recent versions by including these lines in your `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "dev-master"
}
```

Comment: That's giving me an error `ContextErrorException: Runtime Notice: Declaration of Sonata\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::registerAction() should be compatible with FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::registerAction()` How to solve this ?

Comment: It seems to be a different issue that is being tracked [here](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/pull/311). A workaround for this kind of issues could be to use a stable release instead of `dev-master`.

Comment: I don't get it. If I don't use `dev-master`, I got the error that OP posted. Do you mind giving me all your `sonata-project` declarations in your composer.json ? I think I might have a wrong version somewhere.

Comment: Note that the posted error (and my answer) is about `SonataMediaBundle` an yours is about `SonataUserBundle`, they are independent. My suggestion was rolling back to a stable version of `SonataUserBundle` because it seems to be a recent change what triggered this error. Unfortunately I don't use that bundle so I can't share any working configuration, sorry.

Comment: I setted all `sonata-project` bundles to `dev-master` and it now runs. That's quite a mess between all these packages. At first, I just updated dependances with composer and it throws me this error right after.

Answer (score 1):

Update your composer.json from Sonata's sandbox; https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox/blob/2.3-develop/composer.json#L45-L63

```
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "~2.1@dev",
    "sonata-project/seo-bundle": "~1@dev",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "~2.1@dev",
    "sonata-project/page-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
```

Attention on core-bundle": **"~2.2@dev",**